# Is it possible to link a local directory as a folder with images in Overleaf?

Tags: graphics, overleaf, directory

Instead of manually uploading images to an `image` folder in Overleaf, is it possible to link a local directory on my computer as the folder containing the images? I want to be able to put images into the local directory on my computer, instead of having to manually upload these images to Overleaf.

Comment: One way is to link both Overleaf and the local folder to a Github repository and keep them synchronized (see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub). But for most situations that is a bit overkill I guess.

Comment: Overleaf is an online service - it doesn't have visibility onto your local machine and can't access resources there when it is compiling, so you do need to upload all the files it needs to compile your project. As @Marijn noted, an easier way to upload files is using the git-bridge. Some users use the Dropbox synchronization feature for this. These features make it easier to keep files that you are updating locally in sync with your project. Both the git-bridge and Dropbox are premium features, so if you are on the free plan, uploading the files is the only option.